# Texture Paint not working

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

When I try to texture paint, the UV color changes, but there is no change in the material preview or in the final rendering. Does anyone have any advice?

[image]

Blendexchange link
[image]

Comment: Make sure that SnakeTex01 is the image texture that is plugged into your Principled BSDF? Or please pack your images and share your file

Comment: I've updated with the image of my shader.

Comment: could you please pack your images and share the object? https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform

Comment: with this shader setting, tex01 will appear only if tex02 has transparency somewhere, I guess.

Comment: So tex02 should have transparency, uploaded the project file.

Comment: yes it should, if not the tex01 won't appear... after that, it depends of what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we see in your *Shader Editor*, the image called *SnakeTex02* is over the one called *SnakeTex01*, so whatever you do on *SnakeTex01*, you won't see it.